# Can't link contacts in Empathy 3.2

Tags: 11.10, empathy, contacts

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10, with Empathy 3.2. I tried to link any contacts but it does not work. What should I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug and you may have to wait until it is fixed: [Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/folks/+bug/847078)

Answer (score 1):

just install this lib, libfolks-eds25, and restart empathy and will work fine.
type the command bellow in a terminal window.

sudo apt-get install libfolks-eds25

when asks for your password enter the proper one.

close empathy and start it again.